# gRPC request from my rails web-application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grpc, grpc-web

Does anyone know how can I send a request to my gRPC service using rails application?
Like I have my rails web application & I want to send a request to my HELLO gRPC Service when I click a button in the web-app?

Suppose this is my gRPC request

```
call AddCallback (Service Endpoint)
payment_handle (TYPE_STRING) => test
name (TYPE_STRING) => test
url (TYPE_STRING) => test
```

Answer (score 2):

For Ruby gRPC and Rails apps I have found this repo: https://github.com/Gusto/grpc-web-ruby, seems to be doing exactly what you need.

Or I suppose you could set up Envoy to proxy HTTP to gRPC, good explanation is e.g. here: https://blog.envoyproxy.io/envoy-and-grpc-web-a-fresh-new-alternative-to-rest-6504ce7eb880

If you like example more, this one is a good start: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld

Comment: I guess Envoy will be better option.